# How to install lxml in Python 3.4 on Windows machine

Tags: python, windows, pip, lxml

I've been spending hours on this. I'm new to Python and can't see what the solution may be.

I have Python 3.4 and want to work with *.docx*, which requires *lxml*.

The workflow I've done so far is: I go to the Python *lxml* package installer page, but it's quite confusing to know which version I need. I tried with several of them that contained the *34* numbers, both *.exe* and *.tar*. I also tried `pip install lxml3.4.4` and `pip install lxml 3.4.4`. None of them worked either.

This is what the command prompt says when I did `pip install lxml` (it automatically grabs the *lxml 3.4.4* I've downloaded and then prints what you can see in the screenshot):

[image: screenshot of problem. what command prompt returns]

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to repair it? And/or what exact version of *lxml* do I need to install from where? I am really discouraged that this is so difficult. Thanks

Comment: Download [lxml-3.4.4-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) and run `C:\Python34\python.exe -m pip install lxml-3.4.4-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: @cgohlke - oh, just added an answer with the same idea. Btw: good repository :)

Comment: Jeeesus F C! when I followed your instructions I obtained the result I wanted in 5 seconds. Why do things have to be sooo complicated for beginners? Your detailed instructions colidyre and your exact solution @cgohlke should have been shown somewhere very prominently. I really THANK YOU both! but I am still angry that things are set up this way. Massive waste of time for eveyrone involved...I can learn if am given clear instructions but wow just wow. Reminds me of some armies philosophies. "Newbies have to suffer because we suffered before them"...thanks again everyone

Comment: Thanks @colidyre, I am not lazy and don't have a problem with learning. I am just very conscious of my limited time on Earth. Simple terms in the download page like "If you have THIS version of Windows, install this particular package" with a link next to it with the words ("How to install packages for Python?") would do wonders and avoid all this waste of precious human time. There is no point in learning something that is over-complicated for no reason. We're rational, logical beings. We can do better than this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said at the [lxml homepage](http://lxml.de/installation.html), it happened to you:

> If you fail to build lxml on your MS Windows system from the signed and tested sources that we release, consider using the binary builds from PyPI or the unofficial Windows binaries that Christoph Gohlke generously provides.

So you have to download the right wheel file from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

**Step 1: Download appropriate version**

Depending on your machine you have to download the wheel file **lxml‑3.4.4‑cp34‑none‑win32.whl** or **lxml‑3.4.4‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl**, because you want the version for Python3.4 (that's the *34* in cp34).

**Step 2: Open cmd and navigate to the download folder**

I have chosen to open the cmd in administrator mode. But this is probably not necessary for you.

**Step 3: Install wheel file with pip**

Now you have to install the unofficial wheel file with pip. Maybe you can do `pip install pip --upgrade` before you install the wheel file. But this is probably also not necessary for you. To do the installation, just type `pip install <downloaded_file>`.

Or as cgohlke mentioned in his comment to your question: If you can't do `pip install` in cmd directly, this is what you can try: `C:\Python34\python.exe -m pip install <downloaded_file>`. You have to edit the path if Python3.4 is installed elsewhere, of course.

Don't panic. If you try to install the wrong downloaded file (e. g. *win32* instead of *amd64*), it shouldn't break anything. An error message should occur: `<package name> is not a supported wheel on this platform`.