# Python 3.5 - how to install lxml in Windows 7 64 bits

Tags: python, installation, lxml, python-wheel

I am trying to install lxml with Python (32 bits) 3.5.1, on Windows 7 64 bits. I tried `pip install lxml`, but I got the famous error for missing "vcvarsall.bat". If I try to Install visual studio 2015, it requires 6 GB of free space, which I do not have available at the moment, and I'd rather not install a package which I do not plan to use.

I tried downloaded the wheel as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555337/using-lxml-for-python-windows-7-64-bit) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027034/how-to-install-lxml-in-python-3-4-on-windows-machine), but I still get the whl file "is not a supported wheel on this platform". Wheel and pip are upgraded to the latest versions. What am I missing...?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem with Windows 10, all else the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this today.  I found, elsewhere on stackoverflow.com, this two-part and quick solution, which resulted in python no longer complaining when I tried to use lxml:

1. go to [this repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) and download a version which matches your Python installation (the version number, and 32- vs 64-bit.  I use Python 3.5.1 64-bit, installed on Windows 10, so on that page, I chose **lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl**.  You say you use the 32-bit version, so use a version that matches that.

My download directory is d:\Downloads.  Python must be in your PATH environment variable for the next step to work.  Use a command like the following, changing "D:\Downloads" to the pathname to your download directory.  Then, at a DOS prompt, type:

2. **python -m pip install "D:\Downloads\lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl" lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl**

Comment: I tried your solution, as you mentioned in your steps. But I am still getting the same error: `lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`. What can be the issue?